# who initiated log off

Tags: windows, event-log

I found following record in the windows event log:

```
Application popup: Windows : Other people are logged on to this computer. Shutting down Windows might cause them to lose data.

Do you want to continue shutting down?
```

I wonder is it possible to get username of that who tried to login and got that message.

Comment: Doesn't the event log record have a user account attached to it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, no

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to happen when I have more than one profile logged in on my computer (administrator and guest, for example). It means you have launched 2 profiles. The other person is the person who used that profile (it might be you).

Comment: The other person is definitely not me :). That is why I want to know if it is possible find that other user.

Comment: Who else is using your computer?

Comment: If you are the administrator, put a password on the other profiles.